# How to export serverless cloudformation output variables to a file or a task runner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless.yml to create a couple services in AWS cloudformation, specifically: cognitoUserPool and UserPoolClient.

Both of these creations will return IDs that I will use on my flat html files with the cognito library to connect to amazon cognito, so, since I am serving flat files from S3, I need these values to be coded inside the files.

Now I'm looking for a way of automating this, perhaps leaving a placeholder in the files and then running them through a preprocessor that changes the placeholders with the output values before uploading them to S3.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?  My first guess would be to export the output variables from serverless deploy and then use these values on a task runner.

Comment: Yes. Do exactly what you said. Export the values, read them from CloudFormation and write them to a file. You can use placeholders, or you can generate an entire JavaScript file with just those as global variables.

Comment: the problem is: how to read them? is there a way that serverless will output this somewhere? the ideal solution would be for this writing happen automatically just by running the normal serverless deploy command

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986275/1085343 for the serverless way to achieve this without using a plugin

Answer (score 6):

To achieve this without using a Serverless plugin, add the follow to your package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "sls:info": "sls info --verbose | tee ./.slsinfo",
  }
```

This will create the file `.slsinfo` containing your serverless outputs (amongst other things). Run by calling `npm run sls:info`

You can then update package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "sls:deploy": "sls deploy && npm run sls:info",
    "sls:info": "sls info --verbose | tee .slsinfo",
  }
```

Now you can call `npm run sls:deploy` and it will deploy your service and add your outputs to .slsinfo file.

To use the info in `.slsinfo` the easiest way I have found is to use regex. Example below:

```
const slsinfo = require('fs').readFileSync('./.slsinfo', 'utf8');

function getOutput(output) {
  return slsinfo.match(new RegExp('('+output+': )((.?)+)(\\n)'))[2];
}
```

Using the above method you can get your output as follow:

```
const var = getOutput('MyOutputName')
```

Answer (score 4):

To get outputs from `serverless` you can use the [serverless-stack-output](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-stack-output) plugin or you can deduce the stack name and use the `aws` command.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name SERVICE-STAGE --query Stacks[0].Outputs
```

Replace `SERVICE` with your service name and `STAGE` with your stage. You should get a JSON object with the outputs from this command.

If you want to get just specific outputs, try:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name SERVICE-STAGE --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`OUTPUT_KEY`].OutputValue' --output text
```

Replace `SERVICE`, `STAGE` and `OUTPUT_KEY` with the values you want.

On Windows use (the quotes work differently):

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name SERVICE-STAGE --query Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`OUTPUT_KEY`].OutputValue --output text
```

For more details on `--query` see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Comment: Very interesting, any ideas how to suppress the default outputs like FunctionQualifiedArn, ServiceEndpoint, ServerlessDeploymentBucketName ?

Comment: I ended up exporting all to a file and then rewriting it with a gulp task to keep the attributes I need only. The reason is because I would also need a declaration to include it on my javascript such as var settings= {object here} or else I can't really access the contents of the object including it with a simple <script> tag

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on [@kichik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492773/kichik) answer.

The `query` option can be extended to output TOML-like key-value-pairs in the format of `OutputKey=OutputValue`:

```bash
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name nebula-api-dev --query 'join(`\n`, Stacks[0].Outputs[*].join(`=`, [OutputKey, OutputValue]))' --output text
```

Output:

```
LambdaFunctionQualifiedArn=arn:aws:lambda:...
ServerlessDeploymentBucketName=stack...
IamRoleLambdaExecution=arn:aws:iam::...
```

This output can directly be piped to an `.env` file:

```bash
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name nebula-api-dev --query 'join(`\n`, Stacks[0].Outputs[*].join(`=`, [OutputKey, OutputValue]))' --output text > .env
```

And this file can automatically be loaded by a package like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or by the [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables#support-for-env-files).